# Is there a resource listing TV shows that have not come to a 'natural' conclusion?

Tags: ending, film-industry, chronology, cancellation

*[Let me know if this question is inappropriate for this community, as I know it's not specifically listed as being on-topic or off-topic. Likewise, if there is another community I should post this to, let me know.]*

With the advent of streaming services popularised by Netflix, Hulu, etc it is now possible to access a whole range of content that we, as consumers, have never heard of before.

Unfortunately, there are many TV shows that never came to a natural conclusion. By this I mean that they were cancelled **prior** to reaching a conclusion. Some examples of such shows include Caprica, Terra Nova, Jericho, Twin Peaks, Limitless, Firefly (although they *sort of* fixed that with the movie), and the list goes on.

**What I am wondering is if there is a database (or other resource) where people can do a search and check if a particular show was cancelled without some sort of conclusion?**

Ideally IMDb would flag this in some way, but it doesn't. I know it's possible to do a Google, Wikipedia, or other search on individual shows and you may find the answer to this question for that particular show, but often one doesn't. And one can come across a number of short lists and/or articles about shows that were cancelled too soon - but these are often subjective and include shows that did come to a natural end (albeit one fans were unhappy with as they didn't want the show to end).

In a nutshell, I don't like investing my time in a show only to find that it never came to a natural end. There's nothing worse than, say, watching two or three seasons of something only to find that it never concluded. And the possibility of this is much greater now with the proliferation of content on streaming services.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply Google the TV show you are thinking about watching to find out if it was cancelled or if it ended naturally?

Comment: Yes, that's what I do now, but it's hit and miss. Often you can't seem to find a _clear_ answer. And there are also shows which have been cancelled, but they still write some sort of conclusion to it because the decision was made early enough. I don't mind watching a show if it's only a couple of seasons (even one season) so long as it concludes in some way. Personally I think they should just flag this in IMDb in some way. I intend to provide them feedback depending on the result of this question.

Comment: If you think about it, though, what does it even mean for a show "not to come to a conclusion?"  I mean, Firefly was left hanging, for sure, but that show was all about "find a ship, find a crew, keep flying."  To me, any sort of definitive ending would've ruined the "keep flying" angle, so I'm perfectly happy with how it ended.  Another example is Stargate SG-1.  Very open-ended finish, but still very satisfying as such.  I think the best approach is to watch what you want to watch and don't sweat the bad endings.

Comment: I'm referring to a _natural_ conclusion but take your point about Firefly and agree it probably shouldn't be on my list. The same could be said for other shows, particularly sitcoms. I'm talking about shows with a plot requiring some sort of conclusion. E.g. a decision was made to cancel Continuum, but they renewed it for a limited final season of 6 episodes to bring it to some sort of conclusion. I saw that as treating the show's fans with a level of respect. But Caprica ended with no resolution (except for fan fiction).

Comment: Imagine if GoT was cancelled after last season due to falling ratings. Its loyal fans would be up in arms, so i think these types of shows should have enough episodes written to conclude them. But that's another story. :) The point of my question is that there is so much content now readily available of _past_ shows and it'd be good to know in advance of starting to watch them if they had some sort of conclusion. For me it seems like an obvious bit of info to include in IMDb etc.

Comment: The other problem with googling it is that it'll probably get spoiled for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search through TVTropes (Danger Will Robinson!). They have such categories as (derivitatives of [Cancellation](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Cancellation)):

- [Screwed By The Network / Live-Action TV](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ScrewedByTheNetwork/LiveActionTV)
- [No Ending](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoEnding)
- [The Resolution Will Not Be Televised](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheResolutionWillNotBeTelevised)

Comment: Thanks Jack - this is the closest I've seen to what I was looking for and I look forward to using them.

Answer (score 3):

The [closest](https://www.google.pt/search?q=cancelled%20tv%20shows%202016&oq=cancelled%20tv%20sh&aqs=chrome.0.0l2j69i57j0l3.2966j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=cancelled%20tv%20shows) I could find to your request are lists of renewed and cancelled shows, by year:

> [Rotten Tomatoes](https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/article/cancelled-and-renewed-tv-shows-2016-2017/)
>
> [MetaCritic](http://www.metacritic.com/feature/tv-renewal-scorecard-2016-2017-season)
>
> [TvLine](http://tvline.com/2016/10/03/renewed-tv-shows-2017-renewal-scorecard-cancelled-series/)

I didn't find a universal list of all cancelled TV shows (can you imagine how long that would be, though?), but it shouldn't be hard to build some crawler (if you have an IT friend) that just rounds up all the data from these sort of posts.

Anyway, hope this helps. I would also wager that a Wikipedia search for any specific show should tell you whether it was cancelled, on-going, or finished.

PS: Yay, [Mr. Robot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4158110/) has been renewed!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was looking for a _list_ as such, more some sort of database. I suspect what you've suggested is the best I'm going to find (it's what I've been doing at present), but thought it was worth asking. Assuming no consolidated resource exists, I intend to provide feedback to IMDb, Rotten Tomatoes, etc to see if any of them will incorporate some sort of flag in their listings. That seems like the best way to go.